# How to display only name of entered birthday from mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I have made a programme related to birthday app and I want to know how to get birthday of the name entered by user from mysql table.

```
def LoginForm():
    global LoginFrame, lbl_result1
    LoginFrame = Frame(root)
    LoginFrame.pack(side=TOP, pady=80)
    lbl_fullname = Label(LoginFrame, text="Fullname:", font=('arial', 25), bd=18)
    lbl_fullname.grid(row=1)
    lbl_result1 = Label(LoginFrame, text="", font=('arial', 18))
    lbl_result1.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
    fullname = Entry(LoginFrame, font=('arial', 20), textvariable=FULLNAME, width=15)
    fullname.grid(row=1, column=1)
    btn_login = Button(LoginFrame, text="Check", font=('arial', 18), width=35, command=Login)
    btn_login.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, pady=20)
    lbl_register = Label(LoginFrame, text="Add birthday", fg="Blue", font=('arial', 12))
    lbl_register.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    lbl_register.bind('<Button-1>', ToggleToRegister)
    lb1_special = Label(LoginFrame, text="Get Name by Birthdate", fg="Blue", font=('arial', 12))
    lb1_special.grid(row=5, sticky=W)
    lb1_special.bind('<Button-1>', ToggleToCheck)

def SpecialForm():
    global SpecialFrame, lbl_result3
    SpecialFrame = Frame(root)
    SpecialFrame.pack(side=TOP, pady=80)
    lb1_birthdate = Label(SpecialFrame, text="Birthdate(YYYY/MM/DD):", font=('arial', 20), bd=18)
    lb1_birthdate.grid(row=1)
    lb1_result1 = Label(SpecialFrame, text="", font=('arial', 18))
    lb1_result1.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
    birthdate = Entry(SpecialFrame, font=('arial', 20), textvariable=BIRTHDATE, width=15)
    birthdate.grid(row=1, column=1)
    btn_special = Button(SpecialFrame, text="Check", font=('arial', 18), width=35, command=Special)
    btn_special.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, pady=20)
    lb1_login = Label(SpecialFrame, text="Get Birthdate by Name", fg="Blue", font=('arial', 12))
    lb1_login.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    lb1_login.bind('<Button-1>', ToggleToRecheck)
    def Special():
    Database()
    if BIRTHDATE.get == "":
        lbl_result1.config(text="Please complete the required field!", fg="orange")
    else:
        cursor.execute("SELECT fullname FROM `birthday` WHERE `birthdate` = %s", (BIRTHDATE.get(),))
        if cursor.fetchone() is not None:
            cursor.execute("SELECT fullname FROM `birthday` WHERE `birthdate` = %s", (BIRTHDATE.get(),))
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            lbl_result1.config(text="%s" % result)
        else:
            lbl_result1.config(text="Invalid Name", fg="red")

_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!label2"
```

Comment: This is most certainly not valid Python... Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and format your code so that others can read and understand it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL = "SELECT fullname FROM birthday WHERE birthdate = %s"

cursor.execute(SQL, [(birthdate.get())]
```

Realize that commands are case sensitive, therefore:

```
After = Entry()
```

Is not equal to:

```
AFTER = Entry()
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! But this is not the solution of my problem.

Comment: yes thats just an example, I advise you learn OOP. A good book I recommend is "Tkinter GUI Application Development Cookbook: A practical solution to your GUI development problems with Python and Tkinter" by Alejandro Rodas de Paz. That's how I learnt both Tkinter and SQL at once.

Comment: But it doesn't give any solution of my answer.

Comment: Sometimes in life and as well as in coding there are no short easy answers. We have to do the hard work